# Receiving CS1010 Newline in constant when creating a path to a file

Tags: c#, string

Hello I am getting paths dynamically and trying to concatenate the path with a file which I am getting from an email crawler.

For example c:\This\is\anyExample.txt <<< My Intended Goal

GetPath() returns string = c:\This\is

Attachment returns string = anyExample.txt

In code I am doing and get the following

`var path = Getpath()+"\"+ attachment` >>ERROR>>
CS1010  Newline in constant

However I am need the "\" in order to complete c:\This\is\anyExample.txt

Comment: Use double slashes as ``"\\"`` or verbatim string as `@"\"`. But if you _already_ have `c:\This\is\anyExample.txt` string, why do you need to get it again? o.O

Comment: Nope I am trying to get that example sorry I did not clarify, Just found what you said on in an article thanks !!!

Comment: Also, instead of the solution to manual add a path separator, look into Path.Combine() and other Path methods under System.IO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved by using "\\" when trying to create a path